Ranked: To be or not to be
There seems to be a bug in the all time user reputation leagues.
I am simultaneously ranked and not currently ranked:

I am not Schrödinger's cat. What is going on?
Steps to reproduce for my profile:

Go to user profile.

Click on the link just under Reputation.




Scroll up if required.

You will see the first image.

Try it on your own profile.



Just refresh the page.

@ElementsInSpace I've edited the link that shows the issue.

I think this is a duplicate of: Reputation league quarterly view/"own" rep seems broken

By “refresh”, I mean click on one of the time periods, e.g. Year or All Time.

It happens in general to other Time periods too, right now - https://i.sstatic.net/L97KvBdr.png . I mean I guess we could consider this 4 different questions or em-broaden mine, whichever would get a resolution faster :D

"I am not Schrödinger's cat" - Citation needed
